# spyder not keeping variables in memory anymore?

Tags: python, spyder

I recently updated my spyder version to 4, and I really miss a feature that I used to have. In the past, I was able to comment out a line of code that was creating a variable, and still run the code as long as that variable was in memory. This was extremely practical to test things on the fly.
Now, this doesn't work. Is this on purpose or is there a way to reactivate this feature?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

OK, after being confused because I saw this on two versions on two platforms, I tried checking `Tools > Preferences > Run > Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one` under Run Settings.  I had to repeat this in `Run > Configuration per file`
as well.  This fixed the issue, which I was seeing in both version 3.9 on Arch Linux and 4.2.3 on Win10.

I think a lot of people who are migrating from MATLAB to an environment like Spyder might find this to be a serious impediment.  A *lot* of MATLAB use involves tweaking and  running small scripts by hand, essentially using the environment as a mainly script-driven interactive analysis environment.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is one of the really bad things about Matlab and we don't plan to imitate it nor restore the Spyder 3 behavior. It basically leads to unreproducible code because it makes it depend on the state of the console. That we break with Matlab in this regard was also strongly requested by teachers precisely because it made student programs break all the time.

Comment: However, the option is there for people that knows how to look for it.

Comment: Calling that feature of Matlab bad is a matter of opinion.  Matlab is, from way back, more like a command-line drive, programmable interactive "spreadsheet" of sorts.  It wasn't accidental that it worked that way and it doesn't imply that running code is "unreproducible", just that it is cumulative in its effect.  If you want a clean environment in Matlab there is a command to clear current variables and if you want the same in spyder with that checkbox checked there is always Ctrl-<dot> or "%reset".  Sometimes the data in memory is more important than the code.

Comment: Sorry, we had a long discussion about this a year and a half ago and now the matter is settled. As I said, we don't plan to support that behavior again.

Comment: Technically, you're already supporting it with that checkbox.  It's just not the default.  I only really responded because you felt the need to justify it by saying Matlab's choice was "bad".  There's not a good objective standard for making that kind of pronouncement and you don't _need_ to do so.

Oh, and I should've said this first:  thanks for editing my post to point to the option correctly.

Comment: Yep, it's not the default but it's there in case people needs it. And, I'm sorry but, in my mind Matlab's behavior is bad, for the reasons I mentioned above.